# translate python to java : struct.pack('h', int)

Tags: java, python

I have some python code need to phase to java, 
python code :

```
>>> struct.pack('h', 19)
b'\x13\x00'
```

I want to know how it phase to java, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DataOutputStream` with a `ByteArrayOutputStram`

For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(b);
d.writeShort(19);
byte[] result = b.toByteArray();
```

Comment: DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(); 
have to add argument
DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(b);

Comment: @HenryChuang okay, edited, the argument is the ByteArrayOutputStream